# How does assigning primitives to Object works?

Tags: java, autoboxing

Lets say I got those two lines:

```
Object obj;
obj = false;
```

Will *obj* casted into a Boolean (the wrapped class of boolean)?

Comment: you can cast it like that Object obj = new Object(); boolean b = (boolean) obj;

Comment: Why not add some extra lines and do some investigating yourself? System.out.println(obj.getClass())

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object cannot be cast to java.lang.Boolean so this is wrong right @Alan

Comment: https://ideone.com/4xTe3Q

Comment: @YoucefLaidani It is your example that produces this error. Not Alan's.

Comment: mmm, and so where is the problem?

Comment: yes i know that my exemple witch produce the error

Comment: it worked fine for me

http://ideone.com/G8KTCL